# Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details

Tags: react-native, android-studio

Error: Command failed: adb shell am start -n com.getgroceryapp/com.getgroceryapp.MainActivity
at makeError (F:\desuvit\projects\workingbranch\MobileApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)

node version: 12.4.0
npm version: 6.14.7
Using these command for running the app: 1)react-native run-android or npx react-native run-android
also same error

after i upgraded to v12.18.3(node version) also same error.
but i'm trying to run the project getting above error
please help me

advance thanks....

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Having the same challenge. Did you resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Studio File -> Project Structure -> Gradle Settings -> Gradle JDK

and set up as

Embedded JDK

This worked for me after trying so many other options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues:

```
 npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```